# Why does using color break superscript/subscript horizontal spacing?

Tags: math-mode, color, subscripts, superscripts

The below snippet, within an equation array environment, gives the subsequent rendering:

```
F\left[C^{(n-k)}_{P_{ji}}\right]
```

[image: Without color]

But when I add color to the snippet (using the **color** package) as below (**adding line breaks here to facilitate legibility**) in the same environment I get the subsequent bit of unpleasantness:

```
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,1.000}F\left[\color[rgb]{0.000,0.750,0.000}C
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.750,0.000}^{(n-k)}\color[rgb]{0.750,0.750,0.000}
_{P_{ji}}\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,1.000}\right]
```

[image: With color]

I get this whether or not I include the color codes for the super and subscripts prior to the `^` and `_` or within the subsequent `{}`s.

1 **Why am I getting this discrepancy?**

2 **Can I easily correct it in my code using these packages?**

3 **Is this a bug?**

And here is a full document to illustrate:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
\newcommand\independent{\protect\mathpalette{\protect\independenT}{\perp}}
\def\independenT#1#2{\mathrel{\rlap{$#1#2$}\mkern2mu{#1#2}}}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
F\left[C^{(n-k)}_{P_{ji}}\right]
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,1.000}F\left[\color[rgb]{0.000,0.750,0.000}C\color[rgb]{0.000,0.750,0.000}^{(n-k)}\color[rgb]{0.750,0.750,0.000}_{P_{ji}}\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,1.000}\right]\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `\color` instruction inserts an empty math formula which makes it impossible for the subscript to be attached to the preceding atom.

Use `\mathcolor` instead, whenever possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
F\left[C^{(n-k)}_{P_{ji}}\right]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,1.000}F\left[
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.750,0.000}C
^{\mathcolor[rgb]{0.000,0.750,0.000}{(n-k)}}
_{\mathcolor[rgb]{0.750,0.750,0.000}{P_{ji}}}
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,1.000}
\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Never ever use `eqnarray`: see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)

Comment: @Alexis *Penitentiagite!* (From Umberto Eco's “The name of the rose”.)

Comment: Seeing and raising you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgYEuJ5u1K0

Comment: How can I adapt this solution if I want to use \normalcolor?

Comment: @Jakob Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @egreg: Is there a something like `\mathnormalcolor{}` or `\mathtcolor{normal}{}`? (In my case `\colorlet{saved}{.}` solved my problem even better than `\normalcolor` I found out in the meantime.)

Comment: @Jakob Where do you need `\normalcolor`?

Comment: @egreg. I want to define a command that only changes the color of C, but not of the subscript. With \colorlet{saved}{.} I can make it even more robust than with \normalcolor

Comment: @Jakob `\mathcolor{red}{C}^{a}_{b}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149547/discussion-between-jakob-and-egreg).